# Why is there an if statement in the wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The wordpress loop looks like this ( from the docs )

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

It seemed weird to me to check `if ( have_posts() )` before executing `while ( have_posts() )`. After all the exact same check is made on the first iteration of the while loop.

The only situation I can think of the if statement being useful is to execute an else statement to show some conditional text indicating no posts are present.

Are there reasons to include this if statement, that is not really being used? ( I am asking because it looks like redundant code to me, but [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) specify that I should use it )

Comment: If I think here is your answer. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117219/why-should-i-put-ifhave-posts-is-whilehave-posts-not-enough

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action: _“When the posts collection is exhausted (the posts counter matches the total number of posts), the while loop ends and The Loop moves on to whatever instructions it has beyond the while statement, still within the if test. For example, the if might have an else clause with statements to be executed if the posts collection did not contain any data in the first place.”_ – if you don’t have a need for anything like that, then yes, just writing the while loop on its own would do.

Comment: If you wanted to f.e. output a _list_ of posts as UL/LI, then you might want to not output the opening and closing `ul` tags, if there are no posts in the first place. Since `<ul>` belongs before the loop and `</ul>` after it, a case like this would be an example where you might want to wrap the whole thing in such an additional check even if there is no else case.

Comment: Any idea if/how I can mark this question as duplicate of Krupal Panchal's post on StackExchange?

Answer (score 0):

The if statement seemed to be redundant in my example, but overall it is not recommended to omit the if statement.

**The if statement is commonly used to:**

- output something like `no posts found` to indicate that the category in question has no articles assigned to it.
- to decide if a surrounding html ( like an ul ) should be output before and after the articles.

more at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117219/why-should-i-put-ifhave-posts-is-whilehave-posts-not-enough

**What if a new hook is added?**

Another possible issue of not using the if statement is that if the wordpress team ever decided to add a new hook that triggers on the first `$wp_query->have_posts()` call, it would trigger at the wrong time. And if that causes unexpected behavior it would be your fault for not following the spec properly.

**Other devs expect to see a specific structure for the wordpress loop**

I suppose other developers expect to see the entire wordpress loop. So maybe it is a bad idea to have them searching for an if statement that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

the if statement here is used when you want to add some "else" statement when we have no post in our loop

```
else {
    echo 'no posts found!';
}
```